# spring boot square SDK latest version update issue in maven

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, square-connect, square

As currently i am changing version for square java sdk to latest which is 20.1.0.20220616
and current version i am using is 2.20190313.0
so, after dependency resolve in pom.xml it is giving below error message
Cannot resolve com.squareup:connect:20.1.0.20220616

can someone please help me to update my square sdk which is latest and stable ?
also note my pom has below code

```
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

Comment: Remove the bintray reference and use central repository https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.squareup%20a:connect

Comment: Thanks, as this is existing project so can i use maven central for square only ? and how ?

Comment: also when i use https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 same issue happens

Answer (score 1):

A little bit of Googling tells me there is an old obsolete library named 'connect' and a replacement which is named 'square'.

https://developer.squareup.com/docs/sdks/java/quick-start

So use the artifactId 'square', which is indeed in [maven central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup/square).

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.squareup</groupId>
  <artifactId>square</artifactId>
  <version>20.1.0.20220616</version>
</dependency>
```

Disclaimer: I fully expect that your code will no longer compile after that change. They rarely ever decide to make a new library and keep it backwards compatible.

Comment: Thanks it works for me but i need to use https://jcenter.bintray.com so how can i find upto which version of square jcenter supports. so, i can use square with jcenter